# Laravel: Trying to send a mail, variable undefined

Tags: php, laravel, mail-sender

Hi Im trying to send a mail but when I try using the Mail::Send but the variables im creating to have the information to which mail it will be send wont go into the Mail::Send part. I dont know why it always tells me undifined variable, when its defined right on top. Here is the code

```
$result = DB::table('perfil')->where('usuario', $object['usuario'])->first();

        $info = array('confirmation_code' => $result->codigoVerificacion, 'nombre' => $result->nombre);

        $mail = $result->correoVerificado;

        $nombre = $result->nombre.' '.$result->primerPaterno.' '.$result->segundoApellido;

        Mail::send('emails.registro_nuevo_usuario', $info, function($message)
        {

            $message->from('jfeuchter@gmail.com', 'Jurgen Feuchter');

            $message->to($mail, $nombre)
                ->subject('¡Bienvenido a la mejor red social para pedir y dar rides!');
        });
```

If you need more code ask me for it please :P

'Undefined variable: mail' in \app\controllers\registroController.php:103

Comment: what undefined variable? You are leaving out the most critical information :P Ps remove your e-mailaddress.. And did you test the outcome of result? `\dd($result);` Also if you require $result to exists; better use firstOrFail() instead of first()

Comment: So where does `$message` come from?

Comment: My bad here it is hehehe 'Undefined variable: mail' in C\\app\\controllers\\registroController.php:103

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$mail` comes from outside the [closure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), so it's not available inside its scope (unlike `$message` which is passed down as argument by the `send()` method). You need to pass it by using the `use` keyword (I believe the same will happen to `$nombre`)

```
Mail::send('emails.registro_nuevo_usuario', $info, function($message) use($mail, $nombre)
{
 $message->from('jfeuchter@gmail.com', 'Jurgen Feuchter')
          ->to($mail, $nombre)
          ->subject('¡Bienvenido a la mejor red social para pedir y dar rides!');
});
```